# multiple anchor tag with same class. find which anchor tag getting clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have html where I have multiple anchor tag with same class. Juqey selecting 1st anchor tag only. Even i click other anchor tags it returns 1st anchor tag href value. I want jquery which should find anchor tag being clicked in DOM and get that anchor tag href value.

I want to set this href value as var and use that var for other fn.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('.className').click(function (event) {

    var hr = $(this).attr("href");
    alert(hr);
  });
 });
```

Comment: how you can set this var hr to use it for other fn. this var is local only i want to make it global var. how i can do it?

Comment: @RajMehta : Just a suggestion you should try start learning scripting. That is so simple to do..also you have changed your question after my answer this will confuse users anwser looks irrelevant to the context.. If you need to update your question EDIT and Update but not replacing the total content of the original question.